# Registering events on the document without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The [Turbolinks docs] recommend the following:

> register event listeners once on document or window.`

So in other words, they recommend this:

```
$(document).on('click', element, function() {});
```

Over this:

```
$(element).on('click', function() {});
```

Great, makes sense, but I'm now in the process of dropping jQuery, and am having trouble registering listeners on the document using vanilla javascript.

I can attach a listener to the clicked object like so:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {});
```

But this is not the recommended way. How can I attach the listener to the document and not the event target.

Do I have to do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;

  if(target.className === 'my-element') {
    // do stuff in here
  }
});
```

That could get quite hairy. Surely there is another way? Any advice would be great.

Comment: No, this is what jQuery does under the hood. Maybe trying something lighter than jQuery

Comment: Well that pattern is not the best for all situations....

Comment: You may be overthinking this. Setting up your event handlers to make use of event propagation is very useful when, say, you've got 100 cells in a table and you don't want to attach a listener to each cell, but in all other cases `element.addEventListener` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Andy thanks, Rails pretty much _forces_ you to do things that way due to the way Turbolinks works, long story.

Comment: @Andy thanks, Rails pretty much _forces_ you to do things that way due to the way Turbolinks works, long story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with the [Delegated Events](https://github.com/dgraham/delegated-events) library. Github uses it now that they've [dropped jQuery](https://twitter.com/mislav/status/1022058279000842240).

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have to do something like this:

Along those lines, yes. On modern browsers with `closest` (which is being added to the DOM):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target.closest(".my-element");
  if (!target || !this.contains(target)) {
      // Not for this handler
      return;
  }
  // Do stuff here
});
```

In older browsers without, use a loop:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  while (!target.matches(".my-element")) {
      target = target.parentNode;
      if (!target || target == this) {
          // Not for this handler
          return;
      }
  }
  // Do stuff here
});
```

*(Both of those assume you only want to look* within *the root; if the root itself matches, it won't get to the "Do stuff here". Trivial to change it if that's not what you want.)*

Either way, you can readily give yourself a function to do it so you don't have to repeat yourself:

```
function delegate(eventName, root, selector, callback) {
    root.addEventListener(eventName, function(event) {
        var target = event.target.closest(selector);
        if (target && this.contains(target)) {
            return callback.call(this, event);
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

then

```
delegate("click", document, ".my-element", function() {
    // Do stuff here
});
```

---

In a comment, Robert Rocha asked:

> I am curious why the loop in older browsers.

In both examples (with `closest` or with a loop), the reason is that `e.target` may be a *descendant* of the element you want. Suppose you have a table and you want to capture `click` on every table cell, and a table cell contains a `span`. When you click that span, `e.target` will be the `span`, not the `td`, but you still want to trigger your handling of the click. So you have to go up its ancestry to see if anything between it and the root matches.

Comment: Interesting... I am curious why the loop in older browsers.

Comment: @RobertRocha: So that clicks on descendant elements work. I've added a note at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, totally awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library to make this easier, but one smaller than jQuery. I'd recommend something like [`dom-events-delegation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-events-delegation), which lets you do

```
Events.on( document, 'click', '.my-button', myEventHandler );
```

Comment: Thanks @DuncanThacker it's nice to know there's a node module for this, although I think I will go with the function T.J.Crowder came up with :) Cheers.